# SqlCredential - missing assembly/namespace in .Net5.0 mvc6 - rc2

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, dnx50

I'm using vs2015 with .net5.0
- SqlCredential works in DNX 4.5.1 but not DNX Core 5.0 even though I added this line below (under dnxcore50 section) to the dependencies

"System.Data.SqlClient": "4.0.0-rc2-23819"

still getting error msg from the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6948#event-592420962

I posted this question in GitHub as well - and the answer "System.Security.SecureString is no longer present in .Net core because of which SqlClient cannot support SqlCredential"

It's good to know it's not supported now in .net core, will revisit later